# Get the previous page name in PHP (not the entire URL)

Tags: php, http

I have a URL like this;

http://www.mydomain.co.uk/blist.php?prodCodes=NC023-NC022-NC024-NCB33&customerID=NHFGR

Which i grab using HTTP Referrer.  The trouble is i only need the page name i.e. blist.php from the link, not the entire URL as is default using:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Can anyone give me an idea on how to grab that part of the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work, but there **might be other elegant url functions**.

```
$url = 'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/blist.php?prodCodes=NC023-NC022-NC024-NCB33&customerID=NHFGR';

preg_match('/\/[a-z0-9]+.php/', $url, $match);

$page = array_shift($match);

echo $page;
```

Comment: @diEcho well, ... haven't used url functions so much.

Answer (score 8):

try with

```
parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],PHP_URL_PATH);
```

**Note:** this variable doesn't exist in mobile devices.

Comment: Technically speaking this returns `/blist.php` not `blist.php` which I agree is probably fine but if the url had a sub-directory http://www.mydomain.co.uk/mydir/blist.php?prodCodes=NC023-NC022-NC024-NCB33&customerID=NHFGR you would get `mydir/blist.php` whcih may not be fine

Answer (score 7):

Try this one:

```
basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

REF: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Comment: basename will return the query string along with the file name

Answer (score 0):

```
/[\w-]+.php/
```

you can use the regular expression to get only name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] which just gives you the requested page.

You can review all of the $_SERVER variables here:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: This gives me all the variables on top which isn't required.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

check out

http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

focus in on the path ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URL']) portion, then do something like
substr($path,strrpos($path,"/")+1);

Answer (score 0):

```
basename(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],PHP_URL_PATH)
```

This will give you just file name not any sub-directories or the query string

Answer (score 0):

with extension:

```
pathinfo($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PATHINFO_BASENAME);
```

without extension:

```
pathinfo($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```